# NGXS state management : change the state when an action is called and save it to DB

Tags: angular, redux, state, angular7, ngxs

I have several movies, which one can be updated, deleted and liked through NGXS state management pattern.

I want to update my store to show if a movie is liked or not and save the state in the database.

Update and delete actions work, but the like action does not work, I don't understand why. It can't save in DB. If someone can help me I'm stuck. Below is my code, thanks.

db.json

```
"movies": [
{
  "id": 1,
  "title": "Avengers Infinity War",
  "imageUrl": "https://fakeimg.pl/600x600/000000/fff",
  "liked": (here I want to change the status to true or false when clicked)

},
{
  "id": 2,
  "title": "Avengers Endgame",
  "imageUrl": "https://fakeimg.pl/600x600/000000/fff"
}
```

]

Movie.ts

```
 export interface Movie {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 imageUrl: string;
 liked: boolean;
}
```

movie.action.ts

```
 export class UpdateMovie {
      static readonly type = '[Movie] UpdateMovie';
      constructor(public payload: Movie, public id: number) {}
    }

 export class DeleteMovie {
     static readonly type = '[Movie] DeleteMovie';
     constructor(public id: number) {}
    }

  export class LikeMovie {
      static readonly type = '[Movie] LikeMovie';
      constructor(public payload: Movie) {}
    }
```

movie-service.ts

```
 updateMovie(payload: Movie, id: number) {
    return this.httpClient
     .put<Movie>(encodeURI(this.URL_BASE + `movies/${id}`), payload)
   }

deleteMovie(id: number) {
  return this.httpClient
    .delete(encodeURI(this.URL_BASE + `movies/${id}`))
  }

likeMovie(payload: Movie) {
    return this.httpClient
      .post<Movie>(encodeURI(this.URL_BASE + `movies`), payload);
   }
```

movie.state.ts

```
   export class MovieStateModel {
       movies: Movie[];
       selectedMovie: Movie;
       liked: Movie[];
     }

   @State<MovieStateModel>({
      name: 'movies',
      defaults: {
      movies: [],
      selectedMovie: null,
      liked: []
    }
  })

   @Action(DeleteMovie)
   deleteMovie({ getState, setState }: StateContext<MovieStateModel>, {id}: DeleteMovie) {
    return this.movieService.deleteMovie(id).pipe(tap(() => {
      const state = getState();
      setState({
        ...state,
        movies: state.movies.filter(item => item.id !== id)
      });
    }));
   }

 @Action(UpdateMovie)
 updateMovie({ getState, setState }: StateContext<MovieStateModel> {payload, id }: UpdateMovie) {
    return this.movieService.updateMovie(payload, id).pipe(tap((result) =>
  {
      const state = getState();
      const movieList = [...state.movies];
      const movieIndex = movieList.findIndex(item => item.id === id);
      movieList[movieIndex] = result;
      setState({
         ...state,
         movies: movieList
       });
     }));
    }

 @Action(LikeMovie)
 LikeMovie({ getState, setState }: StateContext<MovieStateModel>, {payload}: LikeMovie) {
    return this.movieService.likeMovie(payload).pipe(tap(() => {
      const state = getState();
      setState({
         ...state,
         liked: [...state.liked, payload]
      });
    }));
  }
```

movie-list.component.ts

```
  likeMovie(payload: Movie) {
  this.store.dispatch(new LikeMovie(payload));
}
```

Comment: Is there any errorn being thrown in the console? Does the this.httpClient.post(encodeURI(this.URL_BASE + `liked`)) works (take a look at the browser's console)? Have you tried to put a console.log() inside the @Action(LikeMovie)? Because the reducers is correct.

Comment: Yes I have tried console log but it didn't really help me to debug. I can get the payload representing one movie. But the http request does not work since I can't move to next state and save the new state in the database. It throws errors : `POST http://localhost:3000/movies 500 (Internal Server Error)` `[ErrorHandlerInterceptor] Request error HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 500, statusText: "Internal Server Error", url: "http://localhost:3000/movies", ok: false, …}`

Comment: I have provided my Movie model and my json model of my DB. When I click on a movie I just want to say "movie liked" by changing its status to true or false and save it in the database as a boolean. Thanks for your help

Comment: If any error occurs in the backend (this 500 status indicates this), there is no relation with the javascript implementation. You have to check what is happening in that layer.

Comment: Ok thanks I will check why the http request cannot reach the database and update the selected movie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I have done some tests, and I have removed the request to the DB to make it simple.

Based on my Movie model, I want to update the `liked` property of a movie to true or false when I call the `Like action`, but instead it creates a new state called `liked` with the movie in it...  I know I'm doing something wrong, I can't find a proper answer in the official doc and I'm new with NGXS.

Below are my files:

Movie.ts

```
export interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  imageUrl: string;
  liked: boolean;
}
```

movie.states.ts

```
export class MovieStateModel {
  movies: Movie[];
  selectedMovie: Movie;
}

@State<MovieStateModel>({
  name: 'movies',
  defaults: {
    movies: [],
    selectedMovie: null
  }
})

@Action(LikeMovie)
  LikeMovie({ getState, setState }: StateContext<MovieStateModel>, { payload }: LikeMovie) {
    const state = getState();
    setState({
      ...state,
      liked: payload
    });
  }
```

movie.actions.ts

```
export class LikeMovie {
  static readonly type = '[Movie] LikeMovie';

  constructor(public payload: Movie) {}
}
```

movie-list.component.ts

```
likeMovie(payload: Movie) {
    this.store.dispatch(new LikeMovie(payload));
  }
```

Comment: There's a tiny error in there. Based on your state and models, instead of this `setState({
      ...state,
      liked: payload
    });`, you should have `setState({
      ...state,
      selectedMovie: {
          ...state.SelectedMovie,
          liked: payload.liked
      });`

Comment: But this assumes that you want to change the `liked` property in `SelectedMovie`. If you want to change the `liked` for one of the movies in `movies` array, then you need to loop through the movies, find the one you want to update, do so, and finally put everything back to the `movies` property.

Comment: Well I see, I can find the movie that I want to update with filter function, but I can't access his properties and set the `liked` to true and then push the new state into my `movies` array. That's all I got so far            
   ```@Action(LikeMovie)
  LikeMovie({ getState, setState }: StateContext<MovieStateModel>, { payload }: LikeMovie) {
    const state = getState();
    const movieLiked = state.movies.filter(movie => movie === payload);
    setState({
      ...state,
      movies: [...state.movies, movieLiked]
    });
  }```

Comment: What I would do is: `@Action(LikeMovie)
LikeMovie({ getState, setState }: StateContext < MovieStateModel >, { payload }: LikeMovie) {
  const state = getState();

  const movies = state.movies.map(movie => {
    if (movie.id === payload.id) {
      return ({ ...movie, liked: true });
    }

    return movie;
  });

  setState({ ...state, movies });
}`

Comment: It will be easier to help if you make a simple demo. You can use StackBlitz.

Comment: Thank you very much it works !! Here is the link to the project for StackBlitz but I'm not sure it will run... `https://stackblitz.com/github/alexCodingAcademy/movies-ngxs`   Now I will retry to make an http request to save the new state into DB

Comment: The StackBlitz didn't work. Anyway, I'm glad I could help with the like challenge. Good luck going forward.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow :)

Besides the server error (which Christian has mentioned in the comments already) it seems like there's a small mistake in handling the `LikeMovie` action.

If your `liked` property is `boolean` then you should make sure that a boolean is assigned to it.

```
setState({
  ...state,
  liked: [...state.liked, payload] <-- assigns an array
});
```

The correct way is:

```
setState({
  ...state,
  liked: payload
});
```